# Getting data from a relationship but getting collection error

Tags: laravel

I have two tables `user` and user `details`. Which has one to one relationship.

And I want to display all the data in the users table (name, email, password) and the address and the age only in the user_details table. How can I do it when I have Eloquent relationship made such as

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table ='users';

    protected $fillable = ['user_name', 'email', 'password'];

    public function userdetails(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserDetail','user_id');
    }

}
```

UserDetail.php

```
 <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class UserDetail extends Model
    {
        protected $table ='user_details';

        protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'full name', 'address', 'age'];

        public function users(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        }

    }
```

Maybe I can pass to my view and loop them using foreach?

```
{{$user->user_details->address}}
```

Comment: what you want. i mean do you want to fetch user table data and want to show full name, address, age ,email, username at a place ?

Comment: Yes sir, I want to display all of them in just  a single row. Maybe I can just {{$user->user_details->address}}

Comment: But i keep getting error from it.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Try my answer .@A.Sand. your relationship is correct. i hope you know how to pass data in view and show. if you need help there also then let me know.

Comment: Yes sir I appreciate your help man. But I still get this error. I am on l5.2 sir.

Comment: @A.Sand you should use `userdetails` instead of `user_details` and also you should check if a user has `userdetails` attached to him as I've shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In controller function you can fetch user like this

```
$users = User::with('userdetails')->get();
```

pass this users variable in view and in your view and in your view try this

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  {{ $user->user_name }}
  {{ $user->email }}
  {{ $user->userdetails->full_name }}
  {{ $user->userdetails->address }}
  {{ $user->userdetails->age }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: this error tho : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Are you passing the data correctly in view. in my case you can pass data something like this in your controller funciton . return view('your_view', compact('users'));

Comment: Let me figure and try your answer. Thanks for it

Comment: or first return this variable in $users in controller and check if it is returning something or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to load the data:

```
$users = User::with('userdetails')->get();
```

And then access it:

```
{{ empty($user->userdetails) ? 'No address attached to this user' : $user->userdetails->address }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you everyone, I just queried to the related table. So I query using userdetails

controller:

```
user_detail = UserDetail::with('user')->get();
```